# How can I use in select dropdown with selected value with Angular 9

Tags: html, angular9

How can I use in select dropdown with selected value with Angular 9.

```
            <select [required]="egg.value" [(ngModel)]="protein.egg.sizeEgg"
              #eggSize="ngModel" name="eggSize">
              <option [value]="size" disabled>Size</option>
              <option>S</option>
              <option>M</option>
              <option>L</option>
            </select>
```

in angular 8 it work properly but in angular 9 it do problems inside terminal how can I fix it

terminal error

```
ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.html:67:32 - error TS2339: Property 'size' does not exist on type 'HomeComponent'.

67               <option [value]="size" disabled>Size</option>
                                  ~~~~

  src/app/home/home.component.ts:20:16
    20   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HomeComponent.
src/app/home/home.component.html:67:32 - error TS2339: Property 'size' does not exist on type 'HomeComponent'.

67               <option [value]="size" disabled>Size</option>
                                  ~~~~

  src/app/home/home.component.ts:20:16
    20   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HomeComponent.

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

devtool error

```
home:1 Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:4200/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Please I am wait to your help Thx:-)

Comment: `error TS2339: Property 'size' does not exist on type 'HomeComponent'` => Have you checked `home.component.ts` for a public property called `size`?

Comment: don't have because I don't need it only for show as selected in dropdown as disable

Comment: You need this property to run your component without errors. If it should not refer to the property in the component, you need to remove the brackets. Then it's handled like a string. `<option value="size" disabled>Size</option>`

Comment: When i click i see him as disable but I need to see it as chosen + disable at angular 8 it work - what i did above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added two option to handle.

Note : `[value]` or `[ngValue]` when you mention string value checking any variable inside component. You are getting this error because it checking this.size params but its doesn't exist.

**Option 1**:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="eggSize"
               name="eggSize">
              <option value="size" disabled>Size</option>
              <option value='S'>S</option>
              <option value='M'>M</option>
              <option value='L'>L</option>
            </select>
```

**Option 2**:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="eggSize"
               name="eggSize2">
<option *ngFor="let size of listSize" [ngValue]="size">
       {{size}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**Option 3** :

```
<select [(ngModel)]="eggSize"
               name="eggSize">
              <option [value]="" disabled>Size</option>
              <option [value]='1'>S</option>
              <option [value]='2'>M</option>
              <option [value]='2'>L</option>
            </select>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uq1xjs

Use like this. adding stackblitz for reference.

[image]

Comment: Thank but I need Size will choose and disabled and look at first option

Comment: You can use first option and set size as first option

Comment: This what i did in first time and do all problems

Comment: have you try first option ? Updated stackbliz check once

Comment: yes I did , it shown only at select dropdown but I need see it before chosen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214938/discussion-between-aviboy2006-and-xpopqww).